# Possible to pre-build custom themes in Nebular for Angular

Tags: angular, nebular

Nebular for Angular has a rich themeing system. If you're only using the themes that ship with Nebular, you can opt to use the pre-built themes. Is it possible to pre-build custom themes in the same manner in an effort to reduce bundle size (compile time being a lesser concern)?

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/design-system/create-custom-theme#create-custom-theme

Comment: Multiple times. Everything talks about runtime switching while using scss. I can create a service to switch from one theme to another as they do if I can set it up using pre-built css.